# How to get the size range for fonts

Tags: fonts

What I want to do is have the user select a font from third party font selection combo box and select the font size. How do I go about having the correct range of sizes for that font?

Comment: What constitutes a "correct" range to you?

Comment: this question makes no sense whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts (generally) are vector-based and can be displayed at any reasonable point size. I say "reasonable" becase on a typical display, fonts below 8pts are not terribly useful.

Most Microsoft products give a range starting with 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and then jump by ever-increasing point values up to 72. Depending on your application, you may want to allow a variety of smaller values (like 8-12) and then a few larger values.. a "correct" range really is dependent on how you want to use the fonts.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of fonts are vector-based, i.e. described by lines and quadratic Bézier curves.  This means that you can resize them at will without any loss of quality.  So, in the context of your question, there is no "range of sizes" for a font.